# UITableView Redraw Problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that is showing some very strange behavior when reloading it. For some reason, some of the borders of the table view just go missing (even though I never modified them), but the cell labels shown are correct.

If I just reload a single row, this row looses its borders. If I reload the entire table, the entire table looses its borders.

I am using a white background and the cells have a white background also while the `UITableView` uses a group style.

I haven't seen such behavior before - is this a bug?

Here's how I setup the table:

```
settingsController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

_settingsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
_settingsTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_settingsTable.delegate = self;
_settingsTable.dataSource = self;
_settingsTable.backgroundView = nil;

[settingsController.view addSubview:_settingsTable];
```

and the cells are turned white via this simple code:

```
cell.backgroundView = nil;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, the volume cell lost its borders after having reloaded the cell. Does anyone know what's going on?

**Edit:** Here's how I solved this:

There appears to be a bug in `UITableView`. As you may be aware, `UITableView` does not care about the `backgroundColor` property because its background is loaded in a separate view which by default is a textured image. By setting this to `null`, the table view showed display errors.

I fixed this by just creating a separate white view - now it works fine.

```
UIView*whiteBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_settingsTable.frame];
whiteBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

_settingsTable.backgroundView = whiteBg;

[whiteBg release];
```

Comment: try to set different background colors for the cells and the table view

Comment: No. They need to be white to fit my application's style.

Comment: I thought just to make the cell/table background limit showing up...

Comment: I have already done that previously, but the behavior is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Dont' set the background view of your table to nil. A similar effect can be achieved by setting the backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor]

Same applies to UITableViewCell.

Comment: That's incorrect. Apple loads a background image with the texture for both the iPhone Table View and iPad Table View. `UITableView` ignores the `backgroundColor` property.